# TinyMCE text editor and default HTML

Tags: html, tinymce

I've just started using TinyMCE text editor and I'm a bit confused. I googled my problem, but I haven't found any answer, so I'll ask you.
Is it possible to set default HTML elements to TinyMCE editor, which are NOT possible to delete. What I mean:

```
<textarea id="tinyMCE">
    <div id="impossible-to-delete-default-html">

             Put some changeable HTML like <p>, <a>, <span> etc ...

    </div>
</textarea>
```

What is more, when I want to insert images in my text, should I first upload them from somewhere else and then use them, or there is plugin which allows me to upload them directly?
Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: I usually set default html in the page itself and load the TINYY text between it or after it as i please, then im sure the user can do nothing wrong.

2: Tiny has the option to load pictures directly in your editor

Comment: Thank you. 
1. The reason why I want to set default html in the editor is because I want to allow the user to see how the html is going to be displayed at last. Now I have to write a preview page.
2. How can I configure this option?

Comment: Therefor check the TinyMCE site they have some options about previews

Comment: I checked it, but haven't found anything. But it's ok, it's not a problem. Thank you again. :)